# Issue with Chinese characters in Linux environment with SQL Server 2005

Tags: java, sql-server-2005, jdbc, jtds

I am trying to get Chinese characters from a SQL Server 2005 database server with my web application hosted with Jboss server on a Linux box (RHEL). The issue is that the Chinese characters never get returned from the database, showing some square boxes instead. I have tried both the JTDS drivers as well as the SqlJdbc drivers from Microsoft for this. Interestingly the same combination of database and drivers works fine in a Windows environment with the Chinese characters returned in a string from the result set.

Any help on the issue would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is not a programming question - but rather a support question that may be better served on Super User.

Comment: @GaryRowe - Maybe, maybe not, could be a configuration issue with the web application mentioned in the question.

Comment: Which combination of DB and driver worked on windows?

Comment: Are you sure they never get returned from the database or is your webapp and logging just not rendering them? What happens when you explicitly set the encoding of your output streams to "Cp1252"?

Comment: Seeing "square boxes" usually means that the font you use does not have glyphs for the characters. Converting some of the output to hexadecimal helps to determine if the characters themselves make it through. Try to output eg `Integer.toHexString(str.charAt(0))`

Comment: What environment are you seeing the "boxes" on?  The application server or within the browser?  Are you sure the data is stored correctly in the database?  See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/167152/avoiding-code-change-with-microsoft-sqlserver-and-unicode) for a possibly related question.

Comment: Is it possible to force the charset enconding when the connection gets established?

Answer (score 1):

There's not really enough info about what you're doing with the data between the time it comes out of the database, and the time it gets displayed in the view.  It might be a good idea to print some debug information in both Linux and Windows to see what the differences are for certain System properties, like if you output System.getProperty("file.encoding") in both scenarios, what do you get?

You might want to try using JAVA_OPTS=-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8.

Perhaps the discussion at the link below might help.

https://community.jboss.org/thread/155260?_sscc=t

It doesn't sound like this is a database/driver related problem.